# Selecting unwelded elements of a mesh

Tags: modeling

I am a Max guy learning Blender. How do I select elements of a mesh? By elements, I mean meshes that are joined, but the verts are not welded. So if I modeled a square and then modeled a bolt and then joined the two, how do I select just the bolt, for instance? Thanks!

Comment: Put your mouse cursor over the bolt for example and press L, if you've already selected one or several vertices of the bolt, pess Ctrl L, is it what you want?

Comment: That was it! Thanks, guru!!

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode, you can hoover over a piece and press <kbd>L</kbd> key to select it. Or select a vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked geometry (it can be limited by seams, or materials, or others options, in the black little window that appears in the bottom left of the 3D view, called "Adjust last operation").

In case of more difficult situations you can select some vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to assign them to a vertex group, that you can later select and deselect when needed).

Comment: This one's quite crowded :) Maybe include the Ctrl-G shortcut for assigning to v group, as well. Then I'll delete mine.

Comment: Everybody wants to encourage people coming from others softwares, I guess.